# Python encoding/decoding of str, methods

Tags: python, string

Given a sentence string. Write the shortest word in a sentence. If there are several such words, then output the last one. A word is a set of characters that does not contain spaces, punctuation marks and is delimited by spaces, punctuation marks, or the beginning/end of a line.

Input: sentence = `“I LOVE python version three and point 10”`

Output: "I"

My attempt:

```
sentence = input("sentence: ")
words = sentence.split()
min_word = None
for word in words:
    if len(word) < len(words):
        min_word = word
print(min_word)
```

But output is : 10

Can you help me?

Comment: Some general advice that perfectly applies here: try to run your code with pen and paper, you'll see immediately what goes wrong.

Comment: `if len(word) < len(min_word ):`

Comment: And I was trying to teach a young programmer how to fish... ;(

Comment: but it's error, if len(word) < len(min_word):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this bug because of `if len(word) < len(words):`. It can be `if len(word) < len(min_word):` and to fix `len(None)` you can use this code:

```py
sentence = input("sentence: ")
words = sentence.split()
min_word = words[0]
for word in words:
    if len(word) < len(min_word):
        min_word = word
print(min_word)
```